# Recursive generation of pattern

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to generate all permutations in a list. I know there's built-in functions for this but I would like to do it myself with a recursive function. I'm trying to understand why my attempt doesn't work:

```
chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def recurse(n, value):
    if n > 0:
        for c in chars:
            value += c
            recurse(n-1, value)
    else:
        print value
        return

nchars = 2
recurse(nchars, '')
```

It seems to me my recursion should stop after two iterations (`nchars = 2`) but it keeps going. I would post the current output but it's way to long and messy. Expected output would be:

```
00
01
02
03
...
zx
zy
zz
```

Comment: **Tip:** You can use `string.digits + string.ascii_letters` instead `chars = "0123456789ABCDEF...` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    for c in chars:
        value += c
        recurse(n-1, value)
```

This loop runs 62 times per recursion level, so `value` will grow and grow to have a maximum size of 124. To avoid this cumulative effect, try:

```
    for c in chars:
        recurse(n-1, value+c)
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not go on forever, it goes for `2` recursions only, but the output you get is not what you expected. This is because of the line -

```
value += c
```

This line changes the variable value, so as you iterate over `char` you get larger `value` and recurse with this larger value, this is wrong, you do not need to change the `value` variable, instead you can do -

```
def recurse(n, value):
    if n > 0:
        for c in chars:
            recurse(n-1, value + c)
    else:
        print value
        return
```